# Remove Empty lines from file c#

Tags: c#

Ok I tried several codes. I just can't figure out what to do here.. 
I am doing a quiz. I save the questions and answers like that.

```
 private void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            //checking if question or answer textbox are empty. If they are not then the question is saved
            if (txtquestion.Text != "" & txtanswer.Text != "")
            {
                //saves the question in the questions text
                using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Assignment 2 Solo part\Questions.txt", true))
                {
                    file.WriteLine(txtquestion.Text);
                }
                //saves the answer in the answers text
                using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Assignment 2 Solo part\Answers.txt", true))
                {
                    file.WriteLine(txtanswer.Text);
                }
                MessageBox.Show("Question and Answer has been succesfully added in the Quiz!", "Success!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.None);

                //cleaning the textboxes for a new question and answer
                txtanswer.Text = "";
                txtquestion.Text = "";

            }
               //checks if the question textbox is empty and shows the corresponding message
            else if (txtquestion.Text == "")
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter a question", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            else  //checks if the answer textbox is empty and shows the corresponding message
                if (txtanswer.Text == "")
                    MessageBox.Show("Please enter an answer", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

        }
```

until here everything is fine. The problem is after I delete a question there are empty lines in the file and I tried lots of stuff. I changed 2 times the way i save them. still I can make it work. Now I am also getting an out of bounds error when i delete a question because of the empty spaces that are created. 
Here is the delete code:

```
private void fmrdelete_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {//declaration
            int i=0;
            //loading values to array from file
            string[] qlines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Assignment 2 Solo part\Questions.txt").ToArray();

            foreach (string line in qlines)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(line);
                //saving each line to array possition
                questions[i] = line;
                i++;
                lstboxquestions.Items.Add(line);
            }

            i = 0;
            //loading values to array from file
            string[] alines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Assignment 2 Solo part\Answers.txt").ToArray();

            foreach (string line in alines)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(line);
                //saving each line to array possition
                answers[i] = line;
                i++;
            }

        }
```

---

```
  private void btndelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //declarations
            int line_to_delete;
            int count;
            int i=0;
            //changing the value given from textbox to integer and then saving it
            line_to_delete = Convert.ToInt32(txtans.Text);
            //checking to find the question we want to delete
            for (count = 0; count < 20; count++)
            {
                if (count == (line_to_delete-1))
                {
                   questions[count]= "";

                }
            }
            //clearing file
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Assignment 2 Solo part\Questions.txt",string.Empty);
            //saving to file
            for (count = 0; count < 20; count++)
            {
                //saves the question in the questions text
                using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Assignment 2 Solo part\Questions.txt", true))
                {
                    file.WriteLine(questions[count]);
                }

            }
            //clearing the listbox
            lstboxquestions.Items.Add(" ");
            //loading from file back to array
            string[] qlines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Assignment 2 Solo part\Questions.txt").ToArray();

            foreach (string line in qlines)
            {
                line.Replace("\n\n", "\n");
                Console.WriteLine(line);
                //saving each line to array possition
                questions[i] = line;
                i++;
                lstboxquestions.Items.Add(line);
            }



            //checking to find the answers we want to delete
            for (count = 0; count < 20; count++)
            {
                if (count == (line_to_delete - 1))
                {
                    answers[count] = "";

                }
            }
            //clearing file
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Assignment 2 Solo part\Answers.txt", string.Empty);


            //saving to file
            for (count = 0; count < 20; count++)
            {
                //saves the question in the questions text
                using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Assignment 2 Solo part\Answers.txt", true))
                {
                    file.WriteLine(answers[count]);
                }

            }

            string[] alines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Assignment 2 Solo part\Answers.txt").ToArray();

            foreach (string line in alines)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(line);
                //saving each line to array possition
                answers[i] = line;
                i++;
            }


         }
     }
```

So how to remove the empty lines ?

Comment: Which line is specifically throwing the exception? EDIT: Actually, I see a lot of magic numbers of 20 in your last code set. Why 20? You aren't checking if you have 20 elements in your arrays before you delete.

Comment: answers[i] = line; is giving me the array out of bounds

Comment: Did you try to just not write the empty line? With something like `if (line != string.Empty) { file.WriteLine(line); }`? And for the out of bounds I'm pretty sure it comes from the fact that you use an hardcoded 20 in the `for` loop, instead of the actual number of questions after deletion.

Comment: `btndelete_Click` code doesn't make any sense. where does it check if the line is empty?? it is simply saving all lines...

Comment: Oh, init i at 0 before your last foreach, that's your array out of bounds problem. You are using i before, and continue with its previous value instead of starting from 0.

Comment: I have 20 because I only need 20 questions to save and 20 answers.
I know I should have used a variable instead of a number.
What I do is that i get the file and save a few questions in the file. Then when i want to delete one i go save the questions from file to array,delete the one i dont want to by replacing it with " " then i go and save the array back to file. What i want now is to delete the empty lines after i save the array to file or load it to add a new question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you delete line and then save to file instead of:

```
file.WriteLine(questions[count]);
```

try:

```
if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpac(questions[count]))
    file.WriteLine(questions[count]);
```

Do the same with answers.

**EDIT:**
Have you tried insted of:

```
file.WriteLine(answers[count]);
```

this:

```
if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpac(answers[count]))
    file.WriteLine(answers[count]);
```

Comment: Right on, also, you should also probably put your write operations in a lock block...

Comment: That is actually working for questions file. But for the answers the empty spaces stay.any idea?

Comment: Sometimes copy paste can really be such a drag..
I forgot to change IsNullOrWhiteSpac(questions[count])) to
IsNullOrWhiteSpac(answers[count])).. thnx